# is there special characters or strings cannot be used as key in rapidjson?

Tags: rapidjson

can special characters be used as a part of key?

For example :

```
{
    "+new":"addnew.png"
    "":"empty.png"
}
```

Is this format of rapidjson valid?

Also, is there any special strings that is not valid to use as key?

(I think the earlier question cannot fully answer my question because it does not cover the case of empty string, e.g.:"":"empty.png")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illegal characters in object or JSON key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/illegal-characters-in-object-or-json-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Any valid string can be used as key.
But the shown JSON misses a comma between two members.

Answer (score 0):

By http://www.json.org/:

> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

You can use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate the json string.