# Potential impact of forward slashes in an array name for javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

for example if we have an object's key like `myObject['travelDateAsmm/dd/yyyy']` all those `/` inside the array naming convention for the slice object, will there be any potential issue, in term of security, best practice, etc?

So far we have found no issue for using it, but itself just feel very strange...

Comment: `travelDateAsmm/dd/yyyy` in itself feels weird. Why not just store a `travelDate`, and then give it a method `.as("mm/dd/yyyy")`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8676011/4028085

Comment: Those characters aren't in the array name, they're in the object property names.