# Spring/Rest @RequestBody character encoding

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am using the  environment **Tomcat 7**,and i have deployed my spring/rest 
application.I have a method which is a post method which accepts json  through `@RequestBody` where some keys in **json** have arabic text.When i send the request to the above post method and while parse the jsonobject i am getting question marks in place of `arabic text`.

Comment: Related; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/which-characters-are-valid-invalid-in-a-json-key-name

Comment: Are you sure your request is sent with specified content-encoding? see https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q1

Answer (score 1):

You need to accept the **utf-8** encoding. if you are using POSTMAN to test your API , you can see what your application is accepting as **Accept-Encoding**. [image]

If its not **UTF-8** , then you need to allow this in your application.