# Is it okay to use URLs as JavaScript object literal keys?

Tags: javascript, json

Can you think of any valid URLs that would break the key string naming rules of JS Object literals or JSON?

eg.
`{ 'http://foo': { 'response-data': 'foo' } }`

The JSON spec mentions something about solidus "/" needing to be escaped, but the example above seems to work fine.

References:
[Which characters are valid/invalid in a JSON key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/which-characters-are-valid-invalid-in-a-json-key-name)

http://www.json.org

Comment: When you convert the object to JSON, it will be escaped.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, anything you can get into a string will work.

Comment: Do not concatenate the url to a string, add it to a key in an object instead and when needed use `JSON.stringify(object)`