# Access Hash value when key is a number with undescore (1_1)

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

When I have this:

```
hash = { 1_1: 'foo' }
```

why `hash[1_1]` gives `undefined`, while for ex.:

```
hash = { 1: 'foo' }
```

`hash[1]` returns correct value.

Both objects keys are strings:

```
typeof Object.keys(hash)[0]  /// -> string
```

so why it doesnt convert `hash[1_1]` to string?

p.s. I tested on Chrome and looks like it already supports [numeric separators](http://2ality.com/2018/02/numeric-separators.html)

Comment: why not hash['1_1'] ?

Comment: Code is written not by me, so I am jst wondering how to go here when previously keys were only numbers, but now they also come as `2_4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS engine is disposing of the underscore and converting the key from `1_1` to `11`. But if you wrap it in quotes, it will work:

```
hash = {"1_1": 'foo' }

//{1_1: "foo"}
```

Further reading: [Which characters are valid/invalid in a JSON key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/which-characters-are-valid-invalid-in-a-json-key-name)

Comment: Thats a good catch, I was just hoping I can avoid something like `function(param) { hash[ '' + param] // do something }`

Comment: @NinaScholz My example came from Chrome - but testing in IE and Edge yield the same result.