# How to skip the - character inside a JSON field in JS/type script

Tags: javascript, typescript

One of the JSON field in my JSON file has the field "AlphaWorkStatusChangeInfo-Comment" and I'm trying to add value to that field. But some how the type/JS script is not accepting the "-" in the field.

```
            let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Agri.data));
           
            data.AlphaWorkStatusChangeInfo =  ["other"];
            data.AlphaWorkStatusChangeInfo-Comment = "Had to quit the job";
            data.autoSave = true;
```

What are my options to include/Add the value in the field "AlphaWorkStatusChangeInfo-Comment".

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `data["AlphaWorkStatusChangeInfo-Comment"] = "Had to quit the job";`

Comment: perfect thanks. Will accept this as answer.

Comment: Please research a bit before asking. This has been asked several times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphen is not valid unless you encase it as a string element like so:

```
data["AlphaWorkStatusChangeInfo-Comment"] = "Had to quit the job";
```

See here for more discussion on this topic: [Which characters are valid/invalid in a JSON key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/which-characters-are-valid-invalid-in-a-json-key-name)