# What are the valid characters/values allowed as "keys" in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, object

I tried a few of them,

```
const obj = {
    '`' : 1,
    '@' : 2,
    '^' : 3,
    '-' : 4,
    '?' : 5,
    ']' : 6,
    '*' : 8,
    ')' : 9,
    '/' : 10,
    '>' : 11,
    'ル': 12
}

console.log(obj); //{ '`': 1, '@': 2, '^': 3,'-': 4, '?': 5, ']': 6, '*': 8, ')': 9, '/': 10, '>': 11, 'ル': 12}
```

So my question is, what is that superset of characters(individually not a combination of them, which obviously, would be silly to ask) which can qualify as a key in an JavaScript object?

**EDITED ----**
Definitely not a duplicate! Not sure why is it still marked so!
I've had people comparing JSON with JavaScript objects and deriving answers from them.
I do understand [Which characters are valid/invalid in a JSON key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676011/which-characters-are-valid-invalid-in-a-json-key-name) has some good insights.

But to touch upon whether a few things are allowed or disallowed wrt comparison between JSON and JavaScript "keys" **purely keeping in mind whether those keys are allowed to be typed in or not**, how about **null**, **undefined**?

I'm not getting into how they are internally coerced and inserted as keys or what coercion takes place while retrieving the value using the brackets **[ ]** notation. Purely based on whether you are allowed to type in that value or not, **yes there is a difference between which keys are allowed in JSON vs what is allowed in JavaScript object**.

*null as key in JavaScript object*

```
let x = {null: 10};
for(let key in x){
    console.log(key); //null
    console.log(typeof key); //string
}
```

**Works**

*null as key in JSON*

```
{
    null: 10
}
```

**Doesn't work**

Comment: Since a key can be in the form of a string, literally any character that can be used in a string qualifies for use in the name of a key.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Not exactly, as the OP's question relates to js and the question you linked to relates to JSON

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The other question asks "Are there any forbidden characters in key names, for JavaScript objects or JSON strings?" And regardless, the answer is exactly the same.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery won't agree! See my edits.

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary Your question didn't ask what values are allowed as keys, it asked what characters are allowed in keys. `null` is not a character.

Comment: Fair enough! Have updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any string is allowed as an object key. From [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type):

> Properties are identified using key values. A property key value is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol value. All String and Symbol values, including the empty String, are valid as property keys. A property name is a property key that is a String value.

Comment: This is absolutely NOT a duplicate - at least it's not a duplicate of ANY answer that references JSON. In addition to using null as a key, what about undefined, true or false? In some languages, you can use arrays or objects as keys, what about those? (I don't think you can do that in JavaScript). It's a legitimate question and has nothing to do with JSON.

Sadly, it appears that if you use null, true or false as keys, JavaScript allows it, but converts the value to a string (awful!). So, if you set obj[true] = 42, then you'll find that obj['true'] is set to 42.